# Resizing a matrix into different resolution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, resize

I would need to resize a matrix (without interpolation) in Matlab into different resolution. The image below will highlight what I want:

[image]

Is there any built-in function for this in Matlab? If there isn't, what would be a good way to achieve this result?

Please let me know if my question isn't clear enough. Thank you for any help =)

Comment: I don't know of any built in function, but have you thought about using repmat?

Comment: This is called nearest neighbor interpolation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A = [1 2; 3 4]; %// data
m = 3; %// row repetition factor
n = 3; %// column repetition factor
B = A(ceil(1/m:1/m:size(A,1)), ceil(1/n:1/n:size(A,1)))
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help @LuisMendo appreciate it! =) Very nice :)

Answer (score 5):

there is a easy and fast way in form of the function `kron()`

```
>> kron( [1 2; 3 4], ones(1))
ans =
     1     2
     3     4
>> kron( [1 2; 3 4], ones(2))
ans =
     1     1     2     2
     1     1     2     2
     3     3     4     4
     3     3     4     4
>> kron( [1 2; 3 4], ones(3))
ans =
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     3     3     3     4     4     4
     3     3     3     4     4     4
     3     3     3     4     4     4
```

it is even possible to stretch/shrink dimensions

```
>> kron( [1 2; 3 4], ones(1,2))
ans =
     1     1     2     2
     3     3     4     4
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the **image processing toolbox**

the [imresize](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/imresize.html) function can be used to do this

```
Old=[1,2;3,4]; 
factor=2; % scale factor

New=imresize(Old,factor,'nearest')

New =

     1     1     2     2
     1     1     2     2
     3     3     4     4
     3     3     4     4
```